Query for disabled users in an AD LDS environment
I'm running into an odd issue and can't find any information. I am trying to figure out why queries to return disabled users aren't working and return a value of 0 entries.
The following queries work well in Active Directory, but do not wrk for AD LDS instances:
Get-ADUser -Server 'ADLDS' -SearchBase "Path" -Filter "msDS-UserAccountDisabled -eq '$true'"

Get-ADUser -Server 'ADLDS' -SearchBase "Path" -Filter "Enabled -eq '$false'"

Get-ADUser -Server 'ADLDS' -SearchBase "Path" -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"

Get-ADUser -Server 'ADLDS' -SearchBase "Path" -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(msDS-UserAccountDisabled=true))"

The only queries that worked are as follows:
Get-ADUser -Server 'ADLDS' -SearchBase "Path" -Filter * -Properties * | Where-Object "msDS-UserAccountDisabled" -EQ $true

Get-ADUser -Server 'ADLDS' -SearchBase "Path" -Filter * -Properties * | Where-Object Enabled -EQ $false

Is there a reason the filters on the query side aren't working and why can I only filter on the data after retrieving it? This is a much slower method to get the desired information. Is this a limitation of AD LDS or am I making a mistake with the query?
I am aware of the Search-ADAccount CMDLET. This add further into the confusion as it states it looks at the Enabled property for a false value. But as seen in the queries above, using the Get-ADUser with the filter of Enabled equal false doesn't work. In fact, the error message that it throws is either syntax error, or system.string not supported for extended attribute Enabled.

I'd recommend using Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly

$true and $false should not be quoted.

Tried it both with and without the quotes. No change in behavior. For Active Directory, it works exactly as typed above. It is only AD LDS that is an issue.

regarding Search-ADAccount, how does it perform the search under the hood? Is it looking at a specific property? If so, which one is it. If it's one of the ones in my queries, then why does the above query not work?
The documentation states Specifies a search for accounts that are disabled. An account is disabled when the ADAccount Enabled property is set to false. Yet searching for that with Get-ADUser doesn't work.

All your queries are fine here, I'm assuming this is something related to how ADLDS works.

have a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/technet-wiki/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.  For example, you can use -LDAPFilter '(&(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))' to filter for enabled user accounts

One of the examples is using the -LDAPFilter Parameter and you’ll see it doesn’t work.
I even tried it with looking for enabled accounts and it too doesn’t work in the AD LDS environment.
